# Пагинатор. Отображается обычными цифрами. Сделать отображение кнопочное

Tags: django, bootstrap, pagination, python-2.7

{{ pages }} {{ pages.current_start_index }}-{{ pages.current_end_index }} из {{ pages.total_count }}. {{ pages }}

Сам пагинатор находится в конце HTML страницы, а в отображении стоит сверху. Подскажите пожалуйста, как могу его переместить вниз и дать ему кнопочный вид

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придать кнопочный вид можно с помощью css, переместить вниз нужно в шаблоне, который у вас формирует страницу.